# Makefile 'bonus' rule not identifying changes

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile that have an all and a bonus rule.

For the "all" rule there are two sets of files used: "srcs_files" and the "common_files", if I use make all and then change any of the common_files or srcs_files and run make again, the program identifies the file that was changed creates the new object and compiles the program.

The "bonus" rules uses the "common_files" and the "bonus_files" which compiles fine at first, however if I change any of the "common_files" or "bonus_files" and try to do a make bonus again I get the response: `make: 'bonus' is up to date`

Here is the Makefile:

```
NAME = fractol
NAME_B = fractol_b
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
XFLAGS = -lbsd -lmlx -lXext -lX11
COMMON_FILES = quit zoom ft_atof colors_part1 colors_part2
SRCS_FILES = main fractal hooks movement
BONUS_FILES = main_bonus fractal_bonus hooks_bonus movement_bonus newton_bonus
HEADERS_FILES = fractol buttons ft_printf
COMMON = $(addprefix $(C_DIR), $(addsuffix .c, $(COMMON_FILES)))
SRCS = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), $(addsuffix .c, $(SRCS_FILES)))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR), $(addsuffix .o, $(SRCS_FILES)))
OBJS_C = $(addprefix $(OBJS_C_DIR), $(addsuffix .o, $(COMMON_FILES)))
OBJS_B = $(addprefix $(OBJS_B_DIR), $(addsuffix .o, $(BONUS_FILES)))
HEADERS = $(addprefix $(HEADERS_DIR), $(addsuffix .h, $(HEADERS_FILES)))
BONUS = $(addprefix $(BONUS_DIR), $(addsuffix .c, $(BONUS_FILES)))
SRCS_DIR = srcs/
C_DIR = common_srcs/
OBJS_DIR = objs/
OBJS_C_DIR = objs_common/
OBJS_B_DIR = objs_bonus/
HEADERS_DIR = headers/
LIB_DIR = libs/
BONUS_DIR = bonus/

all:
        mkdir -p $(OBJS_DIR)
        mkdir -p $(OBJS_C_DIR)
        make $(NAME)

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_C_DIR)%.o: $(C_DIR)%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_B_DIR)%.o: $(BONUS_DIR)%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(NAME): $(HEADERS) $(OBJS) $(OBJS_C) libs
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMMON) $(SRCS) libs/libftprintf.a $(XFLAGS) -o $(NAME)

bonus: $(HEADERS) libs
        mkdir -p $(OBJS_B_DIR)
        mkdir -p $(OBJS_C_DIR)
        make $(NAME_B)

$(NAME_B): $(OBJS_B) $(OBJS_C)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMMON) $(BONUS) libs/libftprintf.a $(XFLAGS) -o $(NAME_B)

$(HEADERS):
        ln printf/srcs/ft_printf.h $(HEADERS_DIR)

libs: $(HEADERS)
        make -C ./printf
        mkdir -p $(LIB_DIR)
        mv ./printf/libftprintf.a $(LIB_DIR)

clean:
        make clean -C ./printf
        rm -rf $(OBJS_DIR)
        rm -rf $(OBJS_C_DIR)
        rm -rf $(OBJS_B_DIR)

fclean: clean
        rm -rf libs
        rm -rf $(HEADERS_DIR)ft_printf.h
        rm -rf $(NAME)
        rm -rf $(NAME_B)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

I was expecting that it the make would identify that there was a change in one of its used file, however this only seems to work with the "all" rule. Is there a way to fix this for the bonus rule? Maybe something that I am missing.

Comment: The question is a pretty good one but it is hard to answer when the answerer cannot practically try it on his own computer. Can you write a much shorter makefile that has the same trouble but lacks extraneous features unrelated to the question? Can you post it with everything the answerer needs to experiment? This would be the usual way of asking a question at StackOverflow.

Comment: `The "bonus" rules uses the "common_files" and the "bonus_files" which compiles fine at first` Look at this part of your Makefile: `bonus: $(HEADERS) libs` Doesn't look like you declare a dependency on either bonus_files or common_files. libs depends on HEADERS, HEADERS is defined from HEADERS_FILES, so there's no dependency on bonus_files or common_files.

Comment: @NickODell I get that, but if you compare with the $(NAME) rule it also is not showing dependency on the srcs_files or common_files. They are showing a dependency on the $(OBJS) and $(OBJS_C) for the $(NAME) rule and $(OBJS_C) and $(OBJS_B) for the bonus rule.
My understanding is that since both rules depends on the objects, which in turn are made from the .c files. If I try to pass the $(HEADERS) and libs dependency to the $(NAME_B) the "make bonus" doesn't even work at first time...

Comment: @thb Good idea, will try to create a simplified version of the file and post it here...

Comment: No, `$(NAME)` has `$(OBJS)` `$(OBJS_C)` in its prerequisite list, but `bonus` does not have `$(OBJS_C)` or `$(OBJS_B)` in its prerequisite list.

Comment: @Beta The thing is: if I add the `$(OBJS_B)` and `$(OBJS_C)` in the bonus prerequisite the first compilation of `make bonus` will fail with the message:
`error: unable to open output file 'objs_bonus/main_bonus.o': 'No such file or directory'` 
Because it still didn't create the `$(OBJS_B_DIR)` folder...

Maybe if I create the folders first without any dependencies then call make to create the objects then proceed to compile the program? Will test it out...

Comment: That's a problem with the object rules, not the `bonus` rule. *You are misplacing responsibilities.*

Comment: @Beta Thanks, moving the `mkdir $(OBJS_B_DIR)` to `$(OBJS_B_DIR)%.o:` rule and the `mkdir $(OBJS_C_DIR)` to `$(OBJS_C_DIR)%.o:` fixed the issue!
It's just odd the the all rule had no such issue...

Comment: Why is it odd?  The `all` target has no prerequisites, so make doesn't try to build anything before running the recipe, so there's no way that any other rule will notice the missing directories.  I think you are confusing yourself with all the invoking of sub-make commands you're doing.

Comment: On the other hand, the rules for `bonus` and `libs` do not create files of those names, but such files (directories) apparently do exist.  Whether `bonus` is considered out of date will be a function of the timestamps of those directories and their dependencies. It appears that you mean for these targets to be phony, but they're not.

Comment: Principles for effective makefiles: (1) minimize use of phony targets; (2) read and understand [*Recursive make Considered Harmful*](https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/) before choosing to engage recursive `make`; (3) every object that is built should be built according to a rule having that object as a target; (4) every rule should specify all its direct prerequisites, and no other prerequisites; (5) prefer to keep it simple.